# Chrome extension push notifications on signalR event

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm working on building an chrome extension that communicates with an external `SignalR HUB` on server side.

I've managed to configure both to communicate with one another if I write the JS code in the pop-up page, the problem with this method is that if the extension is not opened, then it can't get updates (doesn't respond to the raised event).

In order to solve it I read that I should write my event handlers in the `background.js`, so even if the extension pop up is not showing - it would still respond to the event. However, I still need to support a button click on my extension to fire an event - which after reading a bit more is not possible cause I don't have access to the DOM in a background file.

So my question is how do I tackle this issue? how can I, from the client side call a function (or make ajax requests) in the server SignalR HUB? and also receive a response from the server when the popup is not opened.

By response I mean a to update values in the `background.js` and a simple +1 to the value in the icon badge, Something that will notify the user that something happened.

I'm very new to chrome extensions so I would appreciate the help!

This is my current code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started ex1ample",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-2.1.4.min.js", "jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js", "background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "http://localhost:61275/"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
var singalR = {};

$(document).ready(function(){
    singalR.connection = $.hubConnection('http://localhost:61275/signalr/hubs', {useDefaultPath: false});
    singalR.connection.logging = true;
    singalR.roomIndexHubProxy = singalR.connection.createHubProxy('roomIndexHub');

    singalR.connection.start().done(function() {
        // Wire up Send button to call RoomIndexHubProxy on the server.
        console.log('Hub has started');
        $("#btn-join").click(function(){
            singalR.roomIndexHubProxy.invoke('test', 111);
        });
    });

    singalR.connection.error(function (error) {
        console.log('SignalR error: ' + error)
    });

    singalR.roomIndexHubProxy.on('test', function (val) {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: val } );
    });
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>      
    <script src="popup.js"></script> //empty for now
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn-join">Join</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Server Side HUB**

```
public class RoomIndexHub : Hub
    {
        static int val = 0;
        public RoomIndexHub(){

        }

        public async Task test(int k)
        {
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<RoomIndexHub>();
            val++;
            await Task.Delay(4000);
            hubContext.Clients.All.test(val.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. Does `setBadgeText` work now? 2. Have you seen [messaging documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), "Simple one-time requests"?

Comment: 1. no, not in this code. but if I move the background.js code to popup.js it will work (besides the part about running in the background).
2. yes I have, I just wasn't sure if this was the right way to do it, cause I've also seen other options.
do you think that messaging is the best way to handle this?

Comment: 1. I think the permitted url should have `*` for the path component: `"http://localhost:61275/*"` 2. Not if you can do everything in the background script

Comment: 1. you are right. still running in dev mode locally so I didn't encounter an error.
2. as far as I know the background is only used as a script and not an actual page, and even if it had an html page, I can't really load it to the popup- right?

Comment: Ah, in that case yes, the popup script sends a message to the background script's listener requesting the data and the background script responds back either via `sendResponse` or via a new message to the popup's listener. Anyway, if this is what the question is about then try implementing something and in case of problems add the code to the question, because I'm not sure what else to say at this point (I think you can google up the examples of popup<->background communication).

Comment: I will try, thanks again:)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the lifetime of your background page? Set persistence to true so this hidden page in background will "live" all the time and is able to listen to incoming requests.

```js
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
```

This will give you a persistent background page.

Check this: [Chrome documentation for event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages)

Reards
Carsten